# If statement while using getters and setters?

Tags: python, oop, polymorphism

I am trying to return the price of the computer based on "macType" which is the size of the computer. I cannot figure out where to integrate the if statement into my code, ahh!!!

```
class apple:
    def __init__(self,pType,price):
        self.__pType=pType
        self.__price=price

    def setpType(self,pType):
            self.__pType=pType

    def setprice(self,price):
            self.__price=price

    def getpType(self):
        return self.__pType

    def getprice(self):
        return self.__price

class mac(apple):
    def __init__(self,pType,price,macType):
        apple.__init__(self,pType,price)
        self.__price=price
        self.__macType=macType

    def setmacType(self,macType):
            self.__macType=macType

    def setmacPrice(self,price):
        if(macType()=="11Inch"):
            self.__price=float(price*.9)
        elif(macType()=="13Inch"):
            self.__price=price
        elif(macType()=="15Inch"):
            self.__price=float(price*1.2)

    def getmacType(self):
        return self.__macType

    def getprice(self):
        if (self.__macType == "11inch"):
            return super(mac, self).getprice()*.9
        elif (self.__macType == "13inch"):
            return super(mac, self).getprice()
        else:
            return super(mac, self).getprice()*1.1

a1 = apple("computer",1000)
m1 = mac("computer",1000,"11Inch")
m2 = mac("computer",1000,"13Inch")
m3 = mac("computer",1000,"15Inch")

print("a1 is a ",a1.getpType(),"and it costs",a1.getprice())
print("m1 is a ",m1.getmacType(),"and it costs",m1.getprice())
print("m1 is a ",m2.getmacType(),"and it costs",m2.getprice())
print("m1 is a ",m3.getmacType(),"and it costs",m3.getprice())
```

Actual output should show that 11 inch is 900, 13 inch is 1000 and 15 inch is 1100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python string comparison is case sensitive. In your `getprice` method you user `"11inch"`, but you give your construct `"11Inch"` notice the upper- and lowercase i? Does aren't going to compare equal. Just use the same everywhere, or even better, look into the [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) module.

Comment: Omg I feel so dumb, that fixed it. Thank you!!